# Check Printing with MICR E13-B Font

Tags: printing, report, micr

I have spent hours searching for technical info on this subject, but have come up empty.
Like most, I build reports (.NET Winforms app) using a reporting engine like Crystal Reports, DevExpress (my choice), etc. When a special font is needed, just install it on the machine and  set the appropriate display control to use it. I would think this would be the same for MICR. However, the printer vendor (https://www.troygroup.com/shop/printers/micr-printers/m406dn-micr-printer.html) keeps mentioning including PCL commands and can provide no further info. Does anyone have any experience printing 'reports' using MICR font? Is it necessary to use PCL commands? Do I need to scrap using a reporting engine and build something using PCL?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that might run into this, here is the solution.
I downloaded a free MICR E13-B font, used it in the appropriate places on a standard report (I use DevExpress).
Client installed a toner cartridge with magnetic ink in a standard laser printer.
The bank approved the results and it has been in production use for over a month.